# Increase max allowable delay

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, anonymity, deanonymization

1 attack is timing correlation attack. How can I increase the max allowable delay for requests between my computer, guard nodes, exit nodes, website?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can delay your traffic at some hops/relays along the circuit, there is no way to do this. Relays will process connections and circuits as fast as possible (limited by their own bandwidth limits). Tor does not perform any traffic mixing or delays.